# Why does my submitting form web-scraping code doesnt work?

Tags: python, forms, web-scraping

I'm try to access the tables of this site: https://aplicacoes.mds.gov.br/sagirmps/estrutura_fisica/preenchimento_municipio_cras_new1.php

So you need to select one state in the form "Selecione um estado" and then there will be a new form for cities called "Selecione um município". When you select the city you want, you get the table to be scraped. But my code only gets the html code of the initial state of the website:

```
import requests
url = 'http://aplicacoes.mds.gov.br/sagirmps/estrutura_fisica/preenchimento_municipio_cras_new1.php'
data = {'Selecione um estado':'SP - São Paulo', 'Selecione um município': 'Bauru'}
r = requests.post(url, data = data)

r.text
```

I've tried to use `params` instead of `data` on the post request but neither of them worked.

Comment: If you are submitting a json payload, use `requests.post(url, json=data)`

Comment: didn't work too. I'm new with scraping, but I don't think its a json payload. Maybe there is something wrong with the data dictionary? Or  is it always equal to the name that displays in the website?

Comment: You're right, it's not, my mistake. That doesn't necessarily work for form data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needed to ignore SSL Cert errors for me. Try the following (thanks to at @SIM for the review and suggestions)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import pandas as pd
import urllib3; urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
url = 'https://aplicacoes.mds.gov.br/sagirmps/estrutura_fisica/preenchimento_municipio_cras_new1.php'
params ={
    'uf_ibge' : '27',
    'nome_estado' : 'AL - Alagoas',
    'p_ibge' : '2700201',
    'nome_municipio' : 'Anadia'
}


r = requests.post(url, params = params, verify=False).
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
tables = pd.read_html(r.text)
print(tables[1])
```

This was for AL - Alagoas and Anadia

Comment: I'm getting this error: NameError: name 's' is not defined

Comment: I'm still finding it difficult to learn regex. What is the easiest way @QHarr?

Comment: I'm awful at regex but I used the following:  https://www.youtube.com/user/shiffman/search?query=regex    @sim

Comment: I like that person very much. I'll go it through. Thanks.